# How to vertically center an image and make it fill available width

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make a simple webpage that displays a GIF as big as possible but right in the center of the page. I would like the image to be centered vertically. Here is a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6baxu1d/1/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gandalf Sax Guy!</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

</style>

    <img src="http://eul.ddns.net/gandalf/gif.gif"/>

    <audio autoplay sr>
        <source src="http://eul.ddns.net/gandalf/sax.mp3">
    </audio>
```

I'd like the image to be as big as possible, but not distorted, and work dynamically.

As you can see, I'd like the image to have an equal amount of "black space" above and below it.

Comment: Your edit should be a comment response under Sebastian's answer, not an edit to your question. :-)

Comment: Okay, I'll try to remember that for next time. Thanks for clearing my question up, too!

Answer (score 2):

flexbox to the rescue!

```css
#positioning-context {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="positioning-context">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/140/50" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!

I tried the flexbox method but it just wasn't happening for me. Now I just need to get it to fill the screen as best I can. How would you recommend doing that?

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @KhrisAzuaje, although this *works* to a certain extent, the image does not keep its original aspect ratio and is distorted. Any way to fix that?

Comment: What browser are you using? And what is the purpose of this? will the size of the element constantly change? You might need an image resizer, no matter how you do this, if the element resizes to be bigger or smaller than the images original size it will show distorted. I think Chrome resizes images on its own, but other browsers wont.
If this is for a server, lets say to show a background selected by the user or something like that Id recommend a PHP imageresizer

Comment: Read my answer again, hope that will help, if not: tell me more about what youre trying to achieve and we'll figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

translate(-50%) method, more info in comments

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%; 
  /* the above combined with translate -50% will..
  center it horizontally and vertically */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: initial; /* no width setting will size it as its original size */
  width: 100%; /* control image size based on screen width */
  width: 50%; /* try all 3 to see */
  width: 17%;
  /* dont mess with height and it will scale with the width */
  /* or only adjust height and let image width scale to it */
  /* height: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpd0U.jpg?s=48&g=1">
```

CSS Tricks has a great article on the different methods of centering.

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

[fiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/a6baxu1d/3/)